# If $S$ is a minimum $k$- restricted-edge-cut of $G$, then must $G-S$ have exactly two connected components?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

An **edge cut** is a set of edges that, if removed from a connected graph, will disconnect the graph.

For a connected graph $G=(V ,E)$, an edge set $S ⊂ E$ is a $k$**-restricted-edge-cut**, if $G−S$ is disconnected and every connected component of  $G−S$ has at least $k$ vertices.

We can see the concept of $k$- restricted-edge-cuts is one of generalizations of edge cuts. The restricted edge connectivity was  proposed by Esfahanian and Hakimi in [1].

[1] Esfahanian A H, Hakimi S L. On computing a conditional edge-connectivity of a graph[J]. Information processing letters, 1988, 27(4): 195-199. [doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(88)90025-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(88)90025-7)

> PS (Off-topic remarks): They give a polynomial algorithm for computing
> the $2$- restricted-edge-cut of graphs. But I feel that it may not be
> correct. I have been trying to implement this algorithm, but failed,
> see
>
> - [How-To-Compute-The-Restricted edge connectivity](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/235032-How-To-Compute-The-Restrictededgeconnectivity)

For example, we have a graph as follows.

[image]

Then we can check that the edge set $\{(0,1),(0,2)\}$ is a minimum $2$-restricted-edge-cut of the above graph (we note that any cut edge $(0,4)$ or $(0,5)$ is not $2$-restricted-edge-cut).

A minimal edge cut set is an edge cut where no subset is also a cut set.

I know that  the following claim holds.

- A edge cut $S$ is a minimal edge cut if and only if $G-S$ have exactly two connected components.

So a natural question is:

**Question.** If $S$ is a minimum (or minimal) $k$-restricted-edge-cut of $G$, then must $G-S$ have exactly two connected components?

I am looking for counterexamples (or prove it).

Comment: If we take three instances of complete graph $K_r$ and connect them in pairs by three edges $S=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. We obtain a connected graph $G$. The graph $G-S$ consists of three connected components. Is this not a counterexample for $k=r$?

Comment: Now is $S$ a minimum $r$-restricted-edge-cut? ($\{e_1,e_2\}$ is an $r$-restricted-edge-cut with fewer edges than $S$.) I hope I understand correctly.

Comment: I agree with you. Indeed, if $S$ is minimal cut and $u\in S$, then graph $H=G-S+u$ is still connected, but then graph $H-u=G-S$ has exactly two connected components.  Right?

Comment: Yes. A minimal edge cut set is an edge cut where no subset is also a cut set.  In fact, I was just asking if a minimum $k$-restricted-edge-cut is always  a minimal cut. (Note that there is a difference between the meaning of "minimum" and "minimal".)

Comment: It is not very clear how a minimum cut can be a non-minimal cut.

Comment: Any minimum cut is a minimal cut, but the reverse is not always true. These definitions can be extended to restrict edge cuts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142182/discussion-between-licheng-and-kabenyuk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity, use "CC" for "connected component".

> A edge cut $S$ is a minimal edge cut if and only if $G-S$ have exactly two CCs.

While the "only if" direction is true, the "if" direction is wrong since $S$ may contain redundant edges. For example, consider a graph with vertices $a,b,c,d$ and edges $ab,bc,cd,db$. Edge cut $\{ab, bc\}$ is not minimal since $\{ab\}$ is an edge cut, too. Both edge sets "cut" the graph into two CCs.

---

> If $S$ is a minimal $k$-restricted-edge-cut of $G$, then must $G−S$ have exactly two CCs?

Of course. Otherwise $G-S$ has at least three CCs. Since $G$ is connected, there is an edge $e$ in $G$ between two of those CCs.  $e$ must be in $S$. Consider $S'=S-\{e\}$. Here are the CCs of $G-S'$:

- Every CC in $G-S$ other than those two CCs connected by $e$.
- the union of those two CCs in $G-S$ connected by $e$ together with $e$

So $G-S'$ has two CCs. That means $G-S'$ is disconnected. Each CC of $G-S'$ is either a CC of $G-S$ or the union of two CCs of $G-S$ together with $e$. Hence, $S'$ is also a $k$-restricted edge cut, which contradicts with the minimality of $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the theorem involving bonds mixed up by mistake. (Bondy text, 2008, Theorem, 2.15 (P62)) In a connected graph $G$, a nonempty edge cut $∂(X)$ is a bond if and only if both $G[X]$and $G[V\setminus X]$ are connected. The definition of edge cuts  in Bondy book there is a little different.